# Issues trying to get FlexBox to render properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm just learning how to use flex, and am trying to make a simple chat application. I am having an issue where the flexbox wont fill the width of the parent container.

My HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper flex-col">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col content">
      <div class="flex-row">
        Test Test test
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        Bottom
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh; 
}

.footer {
  background-color: #999;  
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #eee;
  flex: initial;
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-row {
  flex: 1;
}

.content {
  background-color: #555;

}
```

I have made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/johnwiseheart/pen/jPgJxo) to demonstrate. I would like class "content" to fill the width: ie the grey box filled with "Test Test Test" and the box with the text bottom.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a flex-item so you have to give it flex properties.

```
   .content {
      background-color: #555;
      flex:1; /* add this */

    }
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WvVmLB)